# URLs amigables con .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

He creado el fichero .htaccess manualmente puesto que no lo tenía y haciendo pruebas para obtener urls amigables, me da un internal server error. El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/private/noticias/([0-9]+)\.html /private/noticias.php?ID=$1 [L]
```

`$1` es una variable puesto que el `ID` la obtengo de forma dinámica con PHP. Sin embargo, me sale el siguiente error en cualquier página de la web:

[image: https://s15.postimg.org/cbcixceu3/Captura_de_pantalla_2017-04-22_a_las_14.58.34.png]

No sé si me estoy dejando algo, o qué es lo que está pasando. Una vez borro el fichero del servidor FTP vuelve a funcionar.

Comment: Voy a preguntarlo directamente al soporte aunque al hablar con ellos les he comentado que era para redirigir las URLs y no me han comentado nada adicional.

Comment: Es fácil de comprobar. Usa un `<IfModule>` encerrando las 2 líneas de Rewrite. Si vuelve a funcionar pero no redirecciona, es que está inactivo. Ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/31351/127

Comment: @Mariano Acabo de probarlo pero me siga dando el mismo error. He recibido también respuesta del soporte y me dicen lo siguiente: "Para redirigir tienes que revisar el codigo, por ejemplo este redirige todo a una web:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.dominionuevo.tld/$1 [R=301,L]

Y así con los demás. Esta web puede ayudarte:

http://www.htaccessredirect.net/". Sigo perdido.

Comment: Bien, no le des importancia al ejemplo de soporte. Si sigue dando el error con el IfModule implica que está habilitado pero no encuentra al archivo. Esto significa que el DocumentRoot está configurado en otra carpeta. No uses la `/` al principio del regex ni en la reescritura. Probá con `RewriteRule ^private/noticias([0-9]+)\.html$ private/noticias.php?ID=$1` ... Y asegurarte de que exista `noticias.php` en esa carpeta

Comment: @Mariano Sigue sin funcionarme. Me han comentado de soporte lo siguiente: Ese tipo de enlaces tienes que gestionarlos en tu cms , ya que seguramente si los modificas desde el .htaccess sin mas tengas problemas de redirección después.

Comment: Probaría sin la primera línea (sin FollowSymLinks), y asegurarme que la codificación del archivo coincide con la del server (ANSI, UTF-8)... Más que eso, la sintaxis es correcta, y podés verlo funcionando en un ejemplo que acabo de subir a un hosting gratuito: http://mariano.freevar.com/64761/private/noticias/45678.html

Answer (score 0):

Buenas tardes,

Prueba así:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^private/noticias/([0-9]+)\.html noticias.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Esta corrección está muy bien, es un error que está teniendo el autor, pero eso no generaría una respuesta 500 server error

Comment: Cierto, gracias por rectificar. Quizás el proveedor no soporte reescritura de URL.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Lo acabo de probar pero me sale el mismo error.

Comment: intenta así                                                                                    
`Options All -Indexes
#RewriteBase /nombre de tu web/
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteRule ^private/noticias/([0-9]+)$ noticias.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 0):

Quizás te sirva de este modo:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  # Activar RewriteEngine
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase / 
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^private/noticias/(\d+)\.html$ private/noticias.php?id=$1
</IfModule>
```

Y en la barra de direcciones se vería así: **`http://example.com/private/noticias/1234567`**